# Assigning pointer to pointer in nasm assembler

Tags: pointers, assembly, nasm

I would like to know that how can I assign a pointer variable address into an another pointer variable in NASM assembler. I mean taking the address.

In C/C++ language, it should be like this:

```
char *p1 = "Hello, World?";

// So here, I can do it easily
char *p2 = p1;
```

In NASM, I've two variable in data section like this:

```
String_01 db 'Hello, World', 0
String_02 dd 0
```

So how the C/C++ assignment can be done in NASM?

Actually I'm very beginner to NASM, so that I need some detail information.
   Please help.

Comment: I am not familiar with C, but maybe like this: `%define String_02 String_01`. Though I have to say, that I see no benefit in doing this.:P

Comment: Sorry, this is not helping me. It looks like macro does not it?

Comment: yeah, it is a macro. When you create variables like "string_01" in NASM, they are actually an address which points to the first Byte where your "variable" is stored. When you are a very beginner to Assembly, you may try to find a good book which explains assembly language. For example "assembly step by step".

Comment: @Blechdose, thanks for suggesting me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String_01 db 'Hello, World', 0
String_02 dd String_01
```

Now *String_02* is a label referring to a pointer to a string at *String_01*.
The address of the first character of "Hello, World" can be found by coding

```
mov esi,String_01
```

or

```
mov esi,[String_02]
```